# Unable to use view_cube command due to issue with wx

Tags: python, image, hypercube

I am seeing following issue:

In [5]: img = open_image("2018-09-21_005.hdr")

In [6]: view_cube(img, bands=[29, 19, 9])

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spectral/graphics/hypercube.py in 
     69 try:
---> 70     import wx
     71     from wx import glcanvas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 view_cube(img, bands=[29, 19, 9])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spectral/graphics/graphics.py in view_cube(data, *args, **kwargs)
    176     to accept keyboard input.
    177     '''
--> 178     from spectral.graphics.hypercube import HypercubeWindow
    179
    180     if not running_ipython():

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spectral/graphics/hypercube.py in 
     71     from wx import glcanvas
     72 except ImportError:
---> 73     raise ImportError("Required dependency wx.glcanvas not present")
     74
     75 DEFAULT_WIN_SIZE = (500, 500)           # Default dimensions of image frame

ImportError: Required dependency wx.glcanvas not present

I used following command to install wx:  "brew install wxpython"

Comment: Apparently you're using `spectral` library, yet you didn't mention it in tags or title. Doing so would increase chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to installation of python package

Use following command to install by pip :

pip install wxpython

And Use following command to install by conda environment :

conda install wxpython